# post request keeps getting denied even though It is included in parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, embedded-ruby

I have a post function in my app that takes in the following parameters: a title, the content of the post, a boolean for anonymity, a boolean for graphic content and a string to record the username of the user who made the post. I have all of these fields specified in the new post form of my rails app. Unfortunately, when I go to submit the post, I receive an error saying: `User must exist`. This is happening because the User parameter is not getting posted even though I have added the parameter in my controller:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :anonymous, :graphic, :user_name);
end
```

My schema also has a parameter for the username:

```
  #db/schema.rb

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "name" # here is the parameter for name
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

I used embedded ruby to supply the name parameter in my post form:

```
    <div class="form-group" >
      <%= form.text_field :user_name, name: :post_user_name, value:current_user.name, type: :hidden %>
    </div>
```

I used inspected element in my browser and it showed that the value was equal to my username so I'm stuck as to where the error is. I had a look at [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg) where the person did a similar thing. He got the same error but he fixed it by adding another permit to his parameters in `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`.

My create method looks like this:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(@post), notice: "Post was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

I have also added `has_many :posts` in my user model as well as `belongs_to :user` in my post model.

I am making a forum app, like reddit. I want to have an edit function for each post. The catch is that I want each user to only be able to edit their own posts, thus I need each post to 'remember' the user it was posted by.

My post table contains the following columns:

```
  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.string "content"
    t.boolean "anonymous"
    t.boolean "graphic"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "user_name"
    t.index ["user_name"], name: "index_posts_on_user_name"
  end
```

When I change `@post.user = current_user` in my create method, to `@post.user_name = current_user`, I get the "User must exist" error

**ANSWER**

The solution was to use user ids rather than user names in my posts table.

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a 1:N setup between User and Post and that you are indeed are using devise (at least it looks like it from the schema)? Also it might be useful to share the **posts_controller create** method. Its likely that you are never setting the User to the post, going by the error and the form (i can post an answer once you do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start from the top here. You don't want to be setting up assocations to anything but the primary key column unless you have an extremely important reason to so. Which isn't the case here - and also your users table doesn't even have a user name.

Ditch that `user_name` column and input and add a `user_id` column to the table:

```ruby
class AddUserToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :posts, :user, null: true
    remove_index  :posts, :user_name
    remove_column :posts, :user_name
  end
end
```

If you want to allow posts that are not assocatiated with a user you need to make the column nullable and make the association optional:

```ruby
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

Creating resources that belong to the current user is an extremely common task and the correct way to do it is always to get the user from the session (or a token) as they are encrypted and difficult to tamper with. With Devise you do this with the `current_user` method.

If you instead add a hidden input with a user id or a user name you're just asking for spoofing as its trivial to input any users id with the web inspector or Postman.

```ruby
def create
  @post = if user_signed_in?
    current_user.posts.new(post_params)
  else
    Post.new(post_params)
  end

  # ...
end
```

Make sure you *do not* permit the `:user_id` attribute in your params whitelist.